# Connecting to softlayer object storage using openstack API library php-opencloud

Tags: laravel-5.1, openstack-swift, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, flysystem, php-opencloud

Is there someone tried to connect to softlayer object storage using the [php-opencloud](https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud) library?

I got 400 bad response when the library trying to make authentication.

From what I see inside the php-opencloud library, It use authentication method described [here](http://developer.openstack.org/api-guide/quick-start/api-quick-start.html#openstack-api-quick-guide), it uses v2/token and softlayer object storage using v1.

Does softlayer object storage that based on the same openstack doesn't support the authentication v2?

I can connect to the object storage using sdk(softlayer-object-storage-php) they provided, it seems use the authentication v1, the problem is that I'm using laravel 5.1 which has the built in filesystem using flysystem(thephpleague/flysystem) that have openstack adapter using php-ocencloud.

It will be very nice and will saving my time to just use the driver rather than I have to build custom driver using softlayer sdk and make me reinvent the wheel.

My Config in the config/filesystems.php

```
'rackspace' => [
        'driver'    => 'rackspace',
        'username'  => '***username from softlayer***',
        'key'       => '***api key from softlayer**',
        'container' => '***my test container***',
        'endpoint'  => 'https://sng01.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1',
        'region'    => 'sng01',
        'url_type'  => 'publicURL',
    ],
```

And I try connect like this :

```
Storage::disk('rackspace')->exists('test');
```

And the error is :

```
ClientErrorResponseException in BadResponseException.php line 43:
    Client error response
    [status code] 400
    [reason phrase] Bad Request
    [url] https://sng01.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1/tokens
```

Comment: please add some parts of your code, so it could get clearer were/what the error could be.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @davejal, I've add the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currenlty softlayer only has endpoints for authentication v1, you can see the valid endpoints in the portal (click view credentials http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/how-do-i-access-object-storage-command-line).

Regards